# How to show detailed info inside NSLog in CoreData? suggest me a solution

Tags: ios, xcode, core-data

I am using foliowin function to fetch all records in application

```
-(NSArray*)recordsInTable:(NSString*)tableName andManageObjectContext:(NSManagedObjectContext *)manageObjContext
{
    NSError *error=nil;
    // **** log objects currently in database ****
    // create fetch object, this object fetch's the objects out of the database
    NSFetchRequest *fetchRequest = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];
    NSEntityDescription *entity = [NSEntityDescription entityForName: tableName inManagedObjectContext:manageObjContext];
    [fetchRequest setEntity:entity];
    NSArray *fetchedObjects = [manageObjContext executeFetchRequest:fetchRequest error:&error];
    return  fetchedObjects;
}
```

And using the following code to fetch the records

```
  NSArray *records=[dbAccessObj recordsInTable:@"Details" andManageObjectContext:managedObjectContext];
    NSLog(@"records %@",records);
```

I am getting a log like this

```
**records (
    "<Details: 0x76374b0> (entity: Details; id: 0x7636730 <x-coredata://CDEF0797-F141-47A7-902D-9689DCD90B83/Details/p1> ; data: <fault>)",
    "<Details: 0x7637770> (entity: Details; id: 0x7636740 <x-coredata://CDEF0797-F141-47A7-902D-9689DCD90B83/Details/p2> ; data: <fault>)",
    "<Details: 0x7637870> (entity: Details; id: 0x7636750 <x-coredata://CDEF0797-F141-47A7-902D-9689DCD90B83/Details/p3> ; data: <fault>)"
)**
```

But I want show the log with all details shoiwngin the record shown below.What is the error I made ?

```
**{
    age = 11;
    fName = "firstName";
    lName = "lastname";
    sId = 4;
})**
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no error in your code. What you see in the array are "faults". From the Core Data Programming Guide:

> Faulting is a mechanism Core Data employs to reduce your application’s
>   memory usage.
>
> ... A fault is a placeholder object that represents a
>   managed object that has not yet been fully realized, or a collection
>   object that represents a relationship.
>
> ... If at some stage a
>   persistent property of a fault object is accessed, then Core Data
>   automatically retrieves the data for the object and initializes the
>   object.

`executeFetchRequest:` returns an array of faults (= place holder objects) to save memory. As soon as you retrieve the attribute of an object, the object is fully initialized and all attributes are visible in the debugger.

For *debugging purpuses (only)*, you can force Core Data to fully initialize all objects in the array by

```
NSArray *allAges = [records valueForKey:@"age"];
NSLog(@"records %@",records);
```

Answer (score 1):

I think that you could use debugDescription. Just write from debug command line:

```
po [coreDataObject debugDescription];
```

It will give you detailed informations.