# Rare Error while reading CoreData: data:<fault> in the CoreData Result

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, core-data

From time to time a rarely error occurs in my project (like every 100th Request). The request of some of my CoreData has `data:<fault>` and i can't use that data. I don't really understand why this happens and how to prevent this behavior.

Wrong data output example:

```
<NSManagedObject: 0x147ea09b0> (entity: ToDo; id: 0xd000000002f40000 <x-coredata://7B4FEA6E-1B36-467E-BE14-53CC2EE8CE21/ToDo/p190> ; data: <fault>)
```

Normal output is something like:

```
<NSManagedObject: 0x147ea0790> (entity: ToDo; id: 0xd000000002f40000 <x-coredata://7B4FEA6E-1B36-467E-BE14-53CC2EE8CE21/ToDo/p189> ; data: {
    created = "2016-02-19 15:04:42 +0000";
    text = "Some Text";
})
```

I get the data with:

```
 let fetchRequest = NSFetchRequest(entityName: "Example")

 var examples:[NSManagedObject]

 do {
            let results =
            try self.managedContext.executeFetchRequest(fetchRequest)
            examples = results as! [NSManagedObject]
 } catch let error as NSError {
            print("Could not fetch \(error), \(error.userInfo)")
 }
```

The problem is in the examples from the results. The code doesn't jump in the catch statement. The examples have the same length as the expected data. In my next request all data are still there. Nothing was lost. The only problem is that this data is empty for this only request.

My problem is in Swift. But i guess Objective C could have the same problem.

Anything helps. Thank you in Advance!

Comment: Faults (https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CoreData/FaultingandUniquing.html) are an expected part of working with Core Data managed objects. A fault will fire and load its data when a persistent property is accessed. What is it that you are doing which makes this a problem for you?

Comment: I do the same as in all my other requests. I load some data. Like i said, it works in 99% of the cases. I don't know what is different in this 1%. I can only recreate this bug if i do the same thing over and over again for many many times. Nothing changes. I know i can solve this problem with simple checking the result but i want to understand the problem to fully prevent it from appearing

Comment: As said above, that is *no error*. As soon as you access any property of the objects, the object will be fully initialized from the persistent store, if necessary. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12399910/how-to-show-detailed-info-inside-nslog-in-coredata-suggest-me-a-solution for a similar issue.

Comment: but what is the "bug"? This looks like expected behavior to me.

Comment: @MartinR Yes that's what i found too. But the problem is that the object won't full initialized. Its empty.

Comment: @Jonah The problem is that the data is empty in this case.

Comment: @JonasSchafft: Have you tried `print(yourObject.text)` or `print(yourObject.valueForKey("text")` ?

Comment: @MartinR i tried to use it and it was empty. But i will try to print it in a second.

Comment: @JonasSchafft why do you think the `Example`'s `data` is empty? That's not what you have shown in this question. You have given an example of the `description` method (called via `print`) returning a string showing that the data is a fault and has not yet been loaded.

Comment: @Jonah I did print it yes. For debug purpose because i want to know why my data is empty. I didn't print with valueForKey.

Comment: @MartinR I tried printing it that way. Its empty. It wont get initialized.

Comment: @JonasSchafft: You should edit your question and show the full code demonstrating the problem. How do you access a property? How do you print the object and what is the output?

Comment: @MartinR if i print it with print(yourObject.valueForKey("text") it prints nil. If i print the object it prints  data: <fault> message

Comment: @MartinR like i said: I do this many many times and everything works fine. Its really rarely. There is no more code i can provide. Its just that if it says "fault data" it wont get initialized when i need it. Its not the normal fault behavior

Comment: I faced this problem two days ago. What @Martin requested is he want to know what is the code that you write to print out the object. Maybe how is your core data auto generated class and how is the relationship between entities that you have in the core data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If anyone is reading this, i solved my problem, or better i know what i did wrong.

The problem was that i called to many coredata requests in a very short time. It seems that there is a limit to it. I just set a maximum number of parallel requests and the problem never appeared again.

Answer (score 1):

You can use

```
fetchRequest.returnsObjectsAsFaults = false
```

and as you access your object use

```
print(yourObject.valueForKey("yourKey")
```